# Using function parameters and arguments in Xcode 8 with C++

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode8

I've only recently started learning to code (About 3 days ago, to be exact!) so I really have no idea what I'm doing, to the point that I'm having trouble researching answers to my questions because I don't really know the terminology for anything.

Anyway, I'm learning on learncpp.com, and I'm up to 1.4a – "A first look at function parameters and arguments".

I tried to run this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

void printValues(int x, int y)
{
std::cout << x << std::endl;
std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
printValues(6, 7); 
return 0;
}
```

Apparently it's supposed to spit out:

6

7

in the console window.

However, when I run it, it just says (lldb) in the console window and in the variable window it says:

[A]x = int (6)

[A]y = int (7)

The program also doesn't seem to finish running as it should – it doesn't spit out the return number at the end and when I try to change it and rerun it it asks if I want to terminate the program that's already running.

If it's any help, it highlights this line in green:

```
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

It might also be worth noting that the tutorials on the website use Visual Studios, so I assume there's a difference between two programs that's causing me to have a problem?

Sorry if there is an obvious way to find the answer to this question, I've done some Googling and I tried watching Youtube tutorials etc. but I can't seem to find anything addressing my issue.  Maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

If anybody would be able to help me or even direct me to where I might find an answer that would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set a breakpoint on that line? Usually the debugger will stop on a line if there's an error, or the developer set a breakpoint on that line. If it's highlighted in green, that's a breakpoint. You should see a blue pointer to the left of the line, like this:

[image]

If you click on it, it will turn light blue and the breakpoint will be disabled. You can then either type "continue" at the prompt, or press the continue button (it's a right-pointing triangle with a rectangle to the left of it, sort of like the "Play/Pause" button on a music player).

To remove the breakpoint, grab the blue arrow and drag it to the left and then let go of it. It should disappear in a puff of smoke.

Comment: Yes, this fixed my problem!

Thank you so much!